# IE10 use BLOB url in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-10

I'm creating a BLOB url and assign this url to the location of an iframe. In Firefox and Chrome this works without problems, in IE10 the content of the BLOB url is not displayed in the iframe. In the IE10 debugger I can see, that the BLOB url is created without problems.

```
var test =
{
   init: function()
   {
      var parts = ["<html><body>test</body></html>"];
      var myBlob = new Blob(parts, {"type":"text\html"}); 
      var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);

      document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.location = blobUrl;
   }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", test.init, true);
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try using feature detection for each BlobBuilder and Blob constructor.

```
if (typeof Blob !== "undefined") {
   // use the Blob constructor
} else if (window.MSBlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder) {
   // use the supported vendor-prefixed BlobBuilder
} else {
   // neither Blob constructor nor BlobBuilder is supported
}
```

Another tip is to use `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` relative to `window`:

```
var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(myBlob);
```

IE is sensible on this! Maybe this help!

Comment: Blob constructor exists, the BlobUrl is created successfully. Unfortunately using window.URL.createObjectURL does not help.

Comment: and tracing out the error on feature detection what kind of message did you receive?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. "Blob" exists, so it executes the code after the first "if", no error occurs.

Comment: Now i see you are calling the function as an object literal. If you are calling the `test.init` with parentheses -- `test.init()` -- does not solve your problem?

Comment: No, this does not solve the problem, instead a new problems occurs. Now the document is not visible in the function, the element test can't be found. In Firefox and Chrome this does not work either, so I'm sure the syntax without () is correct.

Comment: then i have no idea, sorry :(